# Change object color when mouse is in and change it back when it's out JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

The root is `Group` and 3 children has been added to the group: a square from `Rectangle` class, a triangle from `Polygon` class and a circle from `Circle` class. These 3 objects are all built in different colors.

**Task**: when the mouse is on a specific object, change the color of that object. The color will change back if the mouse is out of that object.

Here's what I did:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ColouredShapes extends Application{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group group = new Group();
    // square
    Rectangle square = new Rectangle(40,40);
    square.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    // triangle
    Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
    triangle.setLayoutX(80);
    triangle.getPoints().addAll(
            40.0,0.0,
            80.0,40.0,
            0.0,40.0
    );
    triangle.setFill(Color.RED);
    //circle
    Circle circle = new Circle(20);
    circle.setLayoutX(240);
    circle.setCenterY(20);

    // ************** where everything happens *****************
    group.onMouseMovedProperty().set(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.printf("coordinate X: %.2f, coordinate Y: %.2f\n",event.getX(),event.getY());
            System.out.println(event.getSource());

            if (event.getSource() instanceof Rectangle) {
                square.setFill(Color.MAGENTA);
            } else square.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });


    group.getChildren().add(circle);
    group.getChildren().add(triangle);
    group.getChildren().add(square);

    Scene scene = new Scene(group,700,500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

} }
```

The problem is `event.getSource()` returns a result of `Group@52d9d54c[styleClass=root]` rather than the class of its children. As a result, the child cannot be identified, color won't change when mouse moved in to that child.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`event.getSource()` returns the node which triggered the event, which in this case is the `Group`, since that's the node on which you registered the handler.

Use `onMouseEntered` and `onMouseExited` handlers on each of the individual nodes instead:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ColoredShapes extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group group = new Group();
        // square
        Rectangle square = new Rectangle(40, 40);
        square.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        // triangle
        Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
        triangle.setLayoutX(80);
        triangle.getPoints().addAll(40.0, 0.0, 80.0, 40.0, 0.0, 40.0);
        triangle.setFill(Color.RED);
        // circle
        Circle circle = new Circle(20);
        circle.setLayoutX(240);
        circle.setCenterY(20);

        registerHandler(square, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA);
        registerHandler(triangle, Color.RED, Color.MAGENTA);
        registerHandler(circle, Color.BLACK, Color.MAGENTA);

        group.getChildren().add(circle);
        group.getChildren().add(triangle);
        group.getChildren().add(square);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 700, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void registerHandler(Shape s, Color defaultColor, Color hoverColor) {
        s.setOnMouseEntered( e -> s.setFill(hoverColor));
        s.setOnMouseExited(e -> s.setFill(defaultColor));
    }

}
```

You can also do this without using event handlers at all. Either use bindings:

```
square.fillProperty().bind(Bindings
    .when(square.hoverProperty())
    .then(Color.MAGENTA)
    .otherwise(Color.BLUE));
```

or using CSS:

```
square.getStyleClass().add("square");
```

and then in an external CSS file:

```css
.square {
    -fx-fill: blue ;
}
.square:hover {
    -fx-fill: magenta ;
}
```